# Congruences: Solving $ax \equiv c \pmod m$,

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This is from the Joseph Silverman book on Number Theory

Solving $ax \equiv c \pmod m$,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3QcK.png

I understand upto Step X in the above image. But how does he get from Step X to Step Y?

Comment: I **upvoted** because of your presentation.  My mathSE experience has been that a question is presented more clearly if mathjax rather than an image is used.  Your presentation, which includes embedding red markup into the image, represents a nice exception.

Comment: @user2661923 - :-) I tried for 10 minutes to use MathJax, but then gave up. It would have taken me half hour to compose the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we will have infinitely many solutions such that $au+mv=g$ , where $g=$gcd$(a,m)$ .

Now, let $u_0$ and $v_0$ be one such solution which satisfies $au+mv=g$ .

Given that $g\mid c \implies \frac {c}{g} \in \Bbb Z$ .

Since $au_0+mv_0 =g$ , we get that  $\frac {c}{g} ( au_0+mv_0)=c $

$\implies \frac {c}{g} au_0 + \frac {c}{g} mv_0 = c $.

$\implies \frac {c}{g} au_0 - c = -[\frac {c}{g} mv_0]$

Now, since $\frac {c}{g}$ is an integer , we get that $\frac {c}{g} au_0 \equiv c \pmod  m$

So if we take $x_0= \frac {c}{g}u_0 $, we get a solution that satisfies $ax\equiv c \pmod m $

Do tell me if there is any mistake or something is not clear .

Comment: this is correct. You could also add that there are exactly $g$ incongruent solutions modulo $m$.

Comment: Thank you. "Since c/g is an integer" was the crucial part!!